# Android: post event in google calendar

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I need post the event in google calendar from my android app.
I downloaded gdata-library v.2.1, but can't find any documentation for that.

Answer (score 1):

This site walks you through using the calendar in Android: http://www.developer.com/ws/article.php/3850276/Working-with-the-Android-Calendar.htm

Note that the Calendar API is undocumented, unsupported, and may change in the future.

Answer (score 1):

you can you use GoogleApiJavaClient
see here why :
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/wiki/MigratingToGoogleApiJavaClient

look here for more resource
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/sample/calendar/EventFeedDemo.java - Check the createEvent() method.

HTH !

Comment: If you not sure why you posting such an un-releated links, your posted link is for J2SDK not for android.

Comment: @Faisal Khan - If you know programming then you can work around this. I've used this as reference and my app is working fine.